# javascript get html file from online link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xmlhttprequest

i want to call a html online link using xmlhttprequest with javascript, here is my code
but when  the code arrive to xmlhttp.open it stopped and does not continue the execution

```
function loadXMLDoc(size,downloadfromurl) {
    var xmlhttp;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {

        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            var temp = xmlhttp.responseText;

        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://app.arsel.qa/mobileappspeedtest/samples/256.htm?n=" +  Math.random(), false);

    xmlhttp.send(null);

}
```

Comment: The said target is not supporting CORS so you can't make cross domain ajax request to the resource because of same origin policy restrictions

Comment: Yes exactly i think i must enable CORS in the web service following this link http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is an actual AJAX request to that page.
Cross domain AJAX requests are not allowed by default for security reasons.
However, there are several ways of performing cross domain requests, and you could take a look at how jQuery does it, so you don't have to reinvent the wheel all over again using plain JavaScript. [This article](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.in/2013/09/jquery-cross-domain-ajax-request.html) should be helpful.

Anyway, if you actually want to crawl that page, there are tons of open source libraries for server side scripting languages like Java, PHP, Node.js, etc that are very useful in gathering the content, parsing the HTML and so on, depending on your needs.

Comment: If you set "crossDomain" to true and use JSONP to perform cross domain ajax requests and you check where your request actually goes, you will see it goes to a third party server, not directly to the destination you set up as "url". If I remember well, it was actually a google server, but I might be wrong about the last part.

Comment: According to what I know, jQuery asks the server to wrap the request in a call back function that jquery then inserts in the head. It does not contact any other service.

Comment: I remember seeing this some while ago. It worked, but the request went through sort of a proxy. There are multiple ways of performing cross domain ajax with jquery, as per this article. http://jquery-howto.blogspot.in/2013/09/jquery-cross-domain-ajax-request.html

Comment: You can and have to create a proxy if the server you access does not do CORS/JSONP but jQuery does not do any of that. That is all up to you or a 3rd party proxy that you decide to use

Comment: To be honest, I can't remember exactly the way I configured it, but it just went through that proxy. Sorry for not stating it clearly from the beginning. Cheers!

Comment: If you edit your post to make it clear that enabling crossdomain/jsonp in jQuery does not result in 3rd party servers being used, then I will remove the down vote.

Comment: can't you use JSONP ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSONP for overcoming cross domain barrier.

```
$.ajax({
  type:'GET',
  dataType:'jsonp',
  jsonp: "jsonp",
  url:"http://yoururl.com?callback=callbackFunction"
});


function callbackFunction(data){
  //you can process the data here
  console.log(date)
}
```